# jQuery has() vs parents()

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I want to check if event target is descendant of specific wrapper.

Should I use `has()` function or `parents()`?

```
if($('.wrapper').has(e.target).length){
//do something
}
```

vs

```
if ($(event.target).parents('.wrapper').length){
//do something
}
```

Comment: It's up to you. You could also use `closest()`.

Comment: Use the one you find the most readable.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Ya but `closest()` include element itself, so could be in some specific cases not expected behaviour

Comment: @A.Wolff, indeed, that depends on the use case.

Answer (score 1):

It's up to you. Use whatever you find more readable or convenient.

Method three would be proper [delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):

```
$(document).on("click", ".wrapper *", function (e) {
    // whatever
});
```

Comment: what does * do in this case?

Comment: @user3667832 select any kind of descendants. But i'm not sure how is it related to question?  EDIT: ok i see extrapolation now :)

Comment: @user3667832 Read about event delegation in jQuery. See the link I added to my answer.

Comment: Does OP really need `*`? Looks somewhat inefficient to me

Comment: @PeeHaa No, probably he doesn't, I'm sure he can form a more specific selector. In any case, I would not so easily dismiss the above as inefficient just because there is a `*`. Measure it. I would be extremely surprised if this had any impact at all.

Comment: @PeeHaa You implied it would be slow and that proposition has no leg to stand on. Back up your claims, or don't spread FUD.

Comment: I have no idea. It looks inefficient to me